# !Contains() of List object doesn't work

Tags: c#

I am using `Contains()` to identify something that NOT contain in the list.  So something like,

```
if(!list.Contains(MyObject))
{
//do something
}
```

but, the whole if statement goes to true even though `MyObject` is already in the list.

Comment: You need to show us the code of the Contains method.

Comment: @Timores:  Contains() is a method on List<T>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have the ability to override Equals (or if you just don't want to), you can implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` of your object and pass that in as the second parameter to the Contains method (overload). If your object is a reference type, it would otherwise simply be comparing references instead of the contents of the object.

```
class Foo
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }
}

class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<Foo> Members

    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return x.Blah.Equals(y.Blah);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        return obj.Blah.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

...

```
Foo foo = new Foo() { Blah = "Apple" };
Foo foo2 = new Foo() { Blah = "Apple" };

List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

foos.Add(foo);
if (!foos.Contains(foo2, new FooComparer()))
    foos.Add(foo2);
```

In this scenario, foo2 would not be added to the list. It would without the comparer argument.

Answer (score 9):

What's the type of MyObject? Does it have a properly overriden Equals() method?

Comment: It is user defined object and only has 3 proprieties, 2 strings and 1 integer.

Comment: From MSDN: "The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for reference types [...]. Reference equality means the object references that are compared refer to the same object."

Contains() uses the default equality comparer, which in turn calls Equals() (unless your class implements IEquatable, but that's beside the point). So, don't expect Contains() to have decent behavior if you did not override Equals().

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing to find an object in a `List<T>`, then the parameter in the Contains() method must be the *same instance* as the one in the list.  It will not work if they are two separate but identical instances.

Comment: No need to be the same instance if the class overrides the method Equals and this latter returns true